# internal server error 500 while running flask web app

Tags: python, html, flask

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

The flask app code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index1.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug = True)
```

The index1.html is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is index page...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the error tell you on the console?

Comment: more detail about error message from console would be helpful

Comment: No error in console just warning, problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Flask requires a certain structure. All templates (html files) need to be in a directory `templates`. So, I assume your current structure is something like this

```
project/
|- app.py
|- index1.html
```

Correct? Change it to this

```
project/
|- templates/
|  |- index1.html
|- app.py
```